# How to launch multiple instances of cmd prompt

Tags: powershell

I would like to launch multiple instances of a program called `BIOSPwd.exe`.

I use the program by typing the following into `CMD` prompt:

```
BIOSPwd.exe someInputFile.txt anotherInputFile.txt
```

I would like to do something like the following:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 4; $i++)
{
  BIOSPwd.exe someInputFile$i.txt anotherInputFile$i.txt
}
```

to run multiple instances of the program with `someInputFile1.txt` etc.
However this launches the program from within PowerShell ISE. I'd like it to launch multiple instances of `CMD` with that `BIOSPwd.exe` program running in each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
1..4 | % {
   cmd /c "BIOSPwd.exe someInputFile$($_).txt anotherInputFile$($_).txt"
}
```

Edit: I think the above is running one instance at a time. Try `Start-Process` instead:

```
1..4 | % {
   Start-Process -FilePath "cmd" -ArgumentList "/c BIOSPwd.exe someInputFile$($_).txt anotherInputFile$($_).txt"
}
```